# Select records and view it separately in odoo

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

I'm new to odoo. I created a student model and I need to view boys in a separate tree view.

When I click the save button after inserting a girl or a boy I need to view all the boys in a separate tab under same view..

Did you have any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Edit your question with 1. Your attempt code, 2. Current output and 3. Expected output.

Comment: Also, just to add to @Odedra's comment, take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to separate boys and girls on the same view add a default group_by for gender. Put this in your tree view action context (replace gender with whatever field you're using to identify boys and girls):

```
"{'group_by':'gender'}"
```

As for a separate tree view for boys, create another action and add a domain, like:

```
<field name="domain">[('gender', '=', 'male')]</field>
```

or

```
<field name="domain">[('is_boy', '=', True)]</field>
```